# Generating dynamic diagrams with mermaid js

Tags: javascript, mermaid

i need to create diagrams dynamically using mermaid js. i'm trying the following code but i'm getting an error that says:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createElementNS')
```

```
<div id="graphDiv">

</div>
<button id="renderBtn"></button>
```

```
        import mermaidz from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10.0.2/+esm'
        document.getElementById("renderBtn").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            var element = document.getElementById("#graphDiv");
            var insertSvg = function (svgCode, bindFunctions) {
                element.innerHTML = svgCode;
            };
            var graphDefinition = 'graph TB\na-->b';
            var graph = mermaidz.render('graphDiv', graphDefinition, insertSvg);
        });
```

why is that happening? how can i make this code work or find another way to generate diagrams dynamically?

Comment: its the \n that is the problem. It is not being recognized as a line break

Answer (score 3):

With version 10 there is some changes with render.
Try something like this :

```
var graph = mermaidz.render('graphDiv', graphDefinition).then( insertSvg);
```

Take a look at it : https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#mermaidrender-is-async-and-doesnt-accept-callbacks

Also it's return a object